# jQuery val undefined for dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, undefined

I use the following code to dynamically generate input fields, which I want to parse in a jQuery UI dialog. First, the user enters systems. After a click on the "Confirm systems" button, new input fields for each system are generated. Now, I want to access the data entered in the dynamically generated input fields. However, these values are always undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var systemsArray;
  var div = $("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");
  div.append("<p>" +
    "<label for=\"systems\">Systems:</label>" +
    "<input id=\"systems\" size=40></input>" +
    "<button id=\"systems_btn\">Confirm systems</button>" +
    "</p>");
  $("body").append(div);
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Execute",
      click: function() {
        $("#items").children(".input").each(function() {
          alert(this.val().join(", ") + ". "); // <-- val undefined
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
  $("#systems_btn").click(function() {
    $("#items").empty();
    var fieldSet = $("<fieldset id=\"items\"></fieldset>");
    systemsArray = $("#systems").val().split(",");
    for (const systemID in systemsArray) {
      var label = $("<label for=\"" + systemID + "\">" + "Items for " + systemsArray[systemID] + ":" + "</label>");
      var input = $("<input id=\"" + systemID + "\" size=40></input>");
      fieldSet.append(label);
      fieldSet.append(input);
    }
    $(this).parent().append(fieldSet);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

For clarity, this is what the dialog looks like before pressing the "Execute" button (which crashes, because val() is undefined):
[image: Screenshot of dialog]

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

1.:  `.children(".input")` would select elements with the class input, thats not the case in your code, so i changed to `.children("input")` which will select elements of type input

2.: `this.val()` will not work as .val() is a jquery method, i changed it to `$(this).val()` e.g adding a jquery wrapper to the domelement and voilâ, the alert shows the entered value ;-)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var systemsArray;
  var div = $("<div id=\"dialog\"></div>");
  div.append("<p>" +
    "<label for=\"systems\">Systems:</label>" +
    "<input id=\"systems\" size=40></input>" +
    "<button id=\"systems_btn\">Confirm systems</button>" +
    "</p>");
  $("body").append(div);
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Execute",
      click: function() {
        $("#items").children("input").each(function() {
          alert($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
  $("#systems_btn").click(function() {
    $("#items").empty();
    var fieldSet = $("<fieldset id=\"items\"></fieldset>");
    systemsArray = $("#systems").val().split(",");
    for (const systemID in systemsArray) {
      var label = $("<label for=\"" + systemID + "\">" + "Items for " + systemsArray[systemID] + ":" + "</label>");
      var input = $("<input id=\"" + systemID + "\" size=40></input>");
      fieldSet.append(label);
      fieldSet.append(input);
    }
    $(this).parent().append(fieldSet);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or `this.value`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using not jQuery object, but JS object that does not have `.val()`

Try doing `$(this).val()`